# Как написать функцию на PHP с регулярным выражением чтоб убрать все class="..." и id="..."

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как в данной переменной убрать все class="..." и id="..."

```
$text = '
<p class="size title">Размеры:</p>
<p class="size_1">Длина: <span id="z_1">2</span>м</p>
<p class="size_2">Ширина: <span id="z_2">4</span>м</p>
<p class="size_3">Высота: <span id="z_3">3</span>м</p>';
```

Чтоб в итоге в переменной осталось вот так так:

```
$text = '
<p>Размеры:</p>
<p>Длина: <span>2</span>м</p>
<p>Ширина: <span>4</span>м</p>
<p>Высота: <span>3</span>м</p>';
```

главное что классы могут меняться, но код все равно их зачищал, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$text = '
<p class="size title">Размеры:</p>
<p class="size_1">Длина: <span id="z_1">2</span>м</p>
<p class="size_2">Ширина: <span id="z_2">4</span>м</p>
<p class="size_3">Высота: <span id="z_3">3</span>м</p>';

echo preg_replace('/\s(?:class|id)=".*?"/', '', $text);
```

Вывод:

```
<p>Размеры:</p>
<p>Длина: <span>2</span>м</p>
<p>Ширина: <span>4</span>м</p>
<p>Высота: <span>3</span>м</p>
```

Comment: Не используйте в шаблонах пробелы в качестве пробелов, вместо них используйте символьные классы пробельных символов, или unicod-последовательности.

Comment: @Эдуард ок, поправил

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот (впереди пробел, раз его тоже надо удалять):

```
 (class|id)=.+?"
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5952a

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]