# Как написать регулярное выражение php, которое убирает <p> если найдет в нем атрибут style="display:none;"

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имею переменную

```
$text = "
<p style="display:none;">Текст первый</p>
<p>Текст2</p>
<p style="display:none;">Текст второй)))</p>
<p>Текст4</p>";
```

хотелось бы убрать все блоки где присутствует style="display:none;" и остались только те , где не было этого атрибута
Чтоб получилось вот так:

```
$text = "
<p>Текст2</p>
<p>Текст4</p>";
```

Подскажите как это сделать, пожалуйста

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1157904/398802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярное выражение:
`^(?!.*style="display:none;")<p.*<\/p>$`
где используется негативный просмотр впере `(?!.*style="display:none;")`

---

```php
$re = '/^(?!.*style="display:none;")<p.*<\/p>$/m';
$str = '<p style="display:none;">Текст первый</p>
<p>Текст2</p>
<p style="display:none;">Текст второй)))</p>
<p>Текст4</p>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Сгенерировано автоматически по ссылке:
https://regex101.com/r/u5Uzwr/1/